# rich:accordion collapses all accordionItems on page refresh

Tags: user-interface, jsf-2, richfaces, accordion

I have a rich:accordion which has two rich:accordionItems in it. 
    
       
       
    
Some action in accordionItem 2, makes the accordionItem 1 disabled. Hence, after that action, I re-render the whole accordion so that accordionItem 1 is shown as disabled. But on re-render, though item1 is disabled, item2 is getting collapsed. How can I avoid this? Basically, on rerender, the accordion is always showing item1 as expanded, and collapsing all others. Here, as I'm disabling item1, everything is collapsed. How can I restore the state of the accordion even after re-render or page refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set the `activeItem` attribute of the accordion. ([docs](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.3.X/4.3.3.Final/vdldoc/rich/accordion.html))

```
<rich:accordion activeItem="#{bean.activeItem}">
    <rich:accordionItem name="first">…</rich:accordionItem>
    <rich:accordionItem name="second">…</rich:accordionItem>
</rich:accordion>
```

it points to the name of the `<rich:accordionItem>` and updates when you switch the tabs.

Comment: the method in the bean, should that be setActiveItem? I had a setActiveItem(String activeItem) method in the controller. But I get the below exception : 
@13,137 activeItem="#{bean.activeItem}": Property 'activeItem' not readable on type java.lang.String.

Comment: Ok.. Sorry I didn't add a getter to the activeItem attribute. But the problem now is, the first time when the page tries to load, its accessing the getActiveItem() on the bean, which returns an empty string for the first time. This is breaking the page, giving a null pointer exception

Error Rendering View[/myPage.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.richfaces.component.AbstractAccordion.getActiveItem(AbstractAccordion.java:57)
 at org.richfaces.component.AbstractTogglePanel.encodeBegin(AbstractTogglePanel.java:161)

Comment: You'd need to initialize the String then :). `private String activeItem = "first"`

Comment: Yep.. I did the same - initialized the string to first accordion name and it worked :) But was not really sure if it's the best way to do. Anyway, thanks a lot..!! And, I was using a similar approach earlier for rich:tabPanel. It used to activate the first tab if the activeTab is empty. Not sure why it is failing for accordion.